# Jenkins 2.17 not executing jobs

Tags: jenkins, redhat

I am working on RHLinux, jenkins installed using yum. 
Jobs sit in the queue and go nowhere. Only master, no slave.
Checked node configuration, memory, standard suggestions to no avail
Moved installation from /var/lib/jenkins to /opt/jenkins due to space issues and soft linked /var/lib/jenkins -> /opt/jenkins. Changed value of $JENKINS_HOME in sysconfig. I have no idea where else to look. Anyone?

Comment: Could it be a SELinux issue?

Comment: What sorts of "jobs" are you trying to exec?  Are you using ssh commands in these jobs?

Just looking for a little more info. Post away.

Comment: No nothing unusual. They are ant driven jobs. Checkout from SVN, compile, run junit tests, done.

Comment: OK, I've figured out what the deal was. I had the setting "run as the user initiating the job" in the security configuration. It doesn't like that. I changed it to SYSTEM and all worked.

Comment: Crazy - I'm curious how that was set as I don't believe that is a default setting. Well, either way it's good that you got it working. :)